# ruby app onetimesecret getting : keep getting GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 , getting Oops! You found a bug. Let us know how it happened! page

Tags: javascript, ruby, rubygems, http-status-code-401

i installed the [app](https://github.com/onetimesecret) as was instructed in the README but i keep getting the : Oops! You found a bug. Let us know how it happened! page:
this is how i start it :

```
 bundle exec thin -e dev -R config.ru -p 7143 start
/home/ec2-user/onetimesecret/onetimesecret/lib/onetime/core_ext.rb:30: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/share/gems/gems/attic-0.5.3/lib/attic.rb:13: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/share/gems/gems/gibbler-0.8.9/lib/gibbler.rb:654: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/share/gems/gems/gibbler-0.8.9/lib/gibbler.rb:655: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
2021-04-01 14:38:33 +0000 Thin web server (v1.8.0 codename Possessed Pickle)
2021-04-01 14:38:33 +0000 Maximum connections set to 1024
2021-04-01 14:38:33 +0000 Listening on 0.0.0.0:7143, CTRL+C to stop
E(1617287918):  [:limit, :homepage, "88oij9uyld9inbygnn3j648n9hcl1yt", 5]
undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass
/home/ec2-user/onetimesecret/onetimesecret/lib/onetime/app/helpers.rb:162:in `err'
/home/ec2-user/onetimesecret/onetimesecret/lib/onetime/app/helpers.rb:75:in `rescue in carefully'
/home/ec2-user/onetimesecret/onetimesecret/lib/onetime/app/helpers.rb:41:in `carefully'
/home/ec2-user/onetimesecret/onetimesecret/lib/onetime/app/web/base.rb:10:in `publically'
/home/ec2-user/onetimesecret/onetimesecret/lib/onetime/app/web.rb:14:in `index'
/usr/share/gems/gems/otto-0.4.1/lib/otto.rb:281:in `call'
/usr/share/gems/gems/otto-0.4.1/lib/otto.rb:108:in `call'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-2.1.4/lib/rack/reloader.rb:51:in `call'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-2.1.4/lib/rack/common_logger.rb:35:in `call'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-2.1.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:77:in `block in call'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-2.1.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:61:in `each'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-2.1.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:61:in `call'
/usr/share/gems/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
/usr/share/gems/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
/usr/share/gems/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
/usr/share/gems/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
/usr/share/gems/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
/usr/share/gems/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:195:in `run_machine'
/usr/share/gems/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:195:in `run'
/usr/share/gems/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:75:in `start'
/usr/share/gems/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
/usr/share/gems/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:87:in `start'
/usr/share/gems/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:203:in `run_command'
/usr/share/gems/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:159:in `run!'
/usr/share/gems/gems/thin-1.8.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/thin:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/thin:23:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/cli.rb:494:in `exec'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.15/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:130:in `with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-2.2.15/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
10.0.255.25 - - [01/Apr/2021:14:38:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 - 0.0253
 new static route: /img (/img/favicon.png)
10.0.255.25 - - [01/Apr/2021:14:38:38 +0000] "GET /img/favicon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 189 0.0004
```

and i keep getting this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

from your description and log, I believe that:

1. the ruby server is running

```
bundle exec thin -e dev -R config.ru -p 7143 start
2021-04-01 14:38:33 +0000 Thin web server (v1.8.0 codename Possessed Pickle)
2021-04-01 14:38:33 +0000 Maximum connections set to 1024
2021-04-01 14:38:33 +0000 Listening on 0.0.0.0:7143, CTRL+C to stop
```

2. this is the error.

```
E(1617287918):  [:limit, :homepage, "88oij9uyld9inbygnn3j648n9hcl1yt", 5]
undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass
/home/ec2-user/onetimesecret/onetimesecret/lib/onetime/app/helpers.rb:162:in `err'
/home/ec2-user/onetimesecret/onetimesecret/lib/onetime/app/helpers.rb:75:in `rescue in carefully'
/home/ec2-user/onetimesecret/onetimesecret/lib/onetime/app/helpers.rb:41:in `carefully'
/home/ec2-user/onetimesecret/onetimesecret/lib/onetime/app/web/base.rb:10:in `publically'
/home/ec2-user/onetimesecret/onetimesecret/lib/onetime/app/web.rb:14:in `index'
```

I don't know what is the name of your software, but from the top of the error-stack message, I believe the error is at:

```
/home/ec2-user/onetimesecret/onetimesecret/lib/onetime/app/helpers.rb:162:in `err'
```

so open this file, and check what happened at `helpers.rb`, line 162.

often, this may be an configure error.

Comment: Thanks i can see the line of code 
but have no idea what is wrong 
https://github.com/onetimesecret/onetimesecret/blob/5186a5761c79ea28eb88367d1ed8cdd92f432c3a/lib/onetime/app/helpers.rb#L162

Comment: please spend several minutes to study how ruby process exceptions. and the error route is out there, please check it one by one from top ( `helpers.rb:162`) to bottom (`web.rb:14`), I believe you will find a clue.

Comment: and I think for further question, you would better go to this product's wiki/issue page, to create a new issue. People there are more professional for your question.